# HTML5 and CSS - Something must be wrong with my rowspan and colspan

Tags: css, html

This is supposed to be a sudoku table. I checked the css elements and everything appears to be in good working order. I think that I made mistakes in the colspan and rowspan in the table. The "greenBox and "goldBox" classes should make the background images span across 3 rows and 3 columns; however, in the sudoku 9x9 table only 9 squares are filled with the background images. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

```
<table class="spuzzle">
        <caption>Sudoku</caption>

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <td class="greenBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td class="goldBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="greenBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>B</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>C</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>D</th>
                <td class="goldBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>9</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="greenBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="goldBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>8</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>F</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>G</th>
                <td class="greenBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="goldBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>1</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="greenBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3"> 
                    <table class="subTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>H</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>I</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            `
    </table>
```

The CSS is posted below. But I believe that it's functioning as it should.

```
    table.spuzzle
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.subTable
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.spuzzle td 
{
    border:5px outset gray;
}

table.spuzzle th
{
    font-size:8px;
    color:gray;
}

tbody th
{
    height:40px;
}

table.subTable td 
{
    font-size:20px;
    color:blue;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid black;
}

td.goldBox
{
    background-image:url("gold.jpg");
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

td.greenBox
{
    background-image:url("green.jpg");
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page this is on? Or a jsfiddle perhaps? How large are your images? You have `background-repeat` set to `no-repeat`,  so if the images are too small, they won't fill the box.

Comment: The images are displaying in 9 of the 81 squares. I really think I messed up in the rowspan and colspan; however, I am not very good when it comes to tables.

Comment: I can't help if you don't provide more to go off of. Here's what I see in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ginovva320/d6ZNF/. Without a relative link to your images, it's impossible to see what's going on. Can you give a screenshot at least?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling a sudoku grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697033/styling-a-sudoku-grid)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to post the screenshot.

Comment: @Jon No way. I saw that post while researching. I actually thought the question, and answers, were all useless.

Comment: What is the size of the background images? Try replacing images with background color to see if the basic affect is right then, look at what is going wrong with the images, perhaps remove `background-repeat:no-repeat;`. See http://jsfiddle.net/d6ZNF/1/ for using solid colors.

Comment: I removed the "background-repeat:no-repeat." It's now working perfectly. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: Check for a typo on those 9. CSS is case sensitive. Also use a tool like Firbug for Firefox (free download) or developer tools in chrome (hit F12) to inspect the suspect elements and see what, if any, CSS classed are applied to them. Seeing we're heading in the right direction.. I'm going to make these an answer.

Comment: @Anid Your first comment was putting me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Thanks for sticking with me. It's perfect now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your background images aren't large enough.

Try replacing images with background color to see if the basic affect is right then, look at what is going wrong with the images, perhaps remove `background-repeat:no-repeat;`. See http://jsfiddle.net/d6ZNF/1/ for using solid colors.

When debugging, also keep in mind that CSS is case-sensitive. I also recommend using a tool like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox (free download) or [developer tools in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) (hit F12) to inspect the suspect elements and see what, if any, CSS classes are applied to them.