# How to make a sudoku grid using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Excuse me for this simple question. I have designed a sudoku grid in the following way.

**Edited(Using Tables):**

```
     <table id="grid" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr class="row">
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>

                    <!--row--></tr>
                     ---------------------------------------------------------
                     ---------------------------------------------------------

                <tr class="row">
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                    <td class="cell"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
                <!--row--></tr>
     </table>
```

> **The CSS for the document is**

```
#game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: 30px;

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
}

#grid {
    width: 378px;
    height: 395px;

    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;

    border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.cell input {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;

    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

But I am unable to make every third column and third row thick so that each 3 * 3 cell block appears distinctly. Can anyone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is actually a valid application for an HTML table.

Comment: Use tables. This is what they are meant for...

Comment: @Diodeus I did it with tables too. But the problem is the same. Every row and column appears similarly.

Comment: You need to target the table cell borders with css, using selectors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling a sudoku grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697033/styling-a-sudoku-grid)

Comment: saw this previously https://www.ashleymills.com/martin/table.html looks pretty cool, just convert the inline styles to a stylesheet and it'll be good

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child(n)` selector to thicker some of your borders : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eBcCI)**

---

as for a `table` , you can use these CSS rules :

```
table {
  margin:1em auto;
}
td {
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border:1px solid;
  text-align:center;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left:solid;
}
td:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right:solid ;
}
tr:first-child {
  border-top:solid;
}
tr:nth-child(3n) td {
  border-bottom:solid ;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19699482/1897572

And check the result here http://jsfiddle.net/plinuxke/j6t5c/

```
<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; }
colgroup, tbody { border: solid medium; }
td { border: solid thin; height: 1.4em; width: 1.4em; text-align: center; padding: 0; }
</style>
<table>
  <caption>Sudoku of the day</caption>
  <colgroup><col><col><col>
  <colgroup><col><col><col>
  <colgroup><col><col><col>
  <tbody>
   <tr> <td>1 <td>  <td>3 <td>6 <td>  <td>4 <td>7 <td>  <td>9
   <tr> <td>  <td>2 <td>  <td>  <td>9 <td>  <td>  <td>1 <td>
   <tr> <td>7 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>6
  <tbody>
   <tr> <td>2 <td>  <td>4 <td>  <td>3 <td>  <td>9 <td>  <td>8
   <tr> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
   <tr> <td>5 <td>  <td>  <td>9 <td>  <td>7 <td>  <td>  <td>1
  <tbody>
   <tr> <td>6 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>5 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>2
   <tr> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>7 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
   <tr> <td>9 <td>  <td>  <td>8 <td>  <td>2 <td>  <td>  <td>5
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to move the floating logic to the cell class, not the input, and you need to set the display property to block, inline blocks have unstyleble margins, which in this case are not convenient at all

```
.cell{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Then you can use :nth-child(3n+1) to clear the floats after every third element

```
.cell:nth-child(3n+1){
  clear:both;
}

.cell input {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcferrans/G5U8s/1/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
<style>

    input {
        aspect-ratio: 1;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #sudoku-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    }

</style>
```