# Generate Array of numbers from sudoku table HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

I have a simple HTML table setup to look like a sudoku board. Each cell is a input with type = number.

I want to use jQuery to extract all of the numbers from each cell and generate an array of arrays. The array will be formatted like this:

```
array = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
          [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2],
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
          [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2],
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
          [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]]
```

Here is a fiddle of my general set up: [Sudoku Board Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kingcharles/uk74ywg1/1/)
the css is taken from this answer [sudoku css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23497700/5217568)

Essentially the HTML is set up like this:

```
<table id='#table'>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>

  .... x9 rows

</form>
```

I want to make a function with jQuery that on the click of a button, it converts each row into an array and puts each array into one array.

My approach:
Use jQuery to select the table. Loop through each table row. Nest a loop to loop over each input and append each value to arrays.

This is what I have so far (it does not work at all. It just logs an empty array, even if I populate the table with values).
    var array = [];

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('table').children('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('input').each(function(){
            array.push($(this).val());
        });
    });
    alert(array);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should have another `array` for each `tr` and after all `td` iterations, push that array in main array

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uk74ywg1/5/)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var array = [];
  $('#table').find('tr').each(function() {
    var arr = [];
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    array.push(arr);
  });
  console.log(array);
});
```

```css
table {
  margin: 1em auto;
}
td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left: solid;
}
td:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: solid;
}
tr:first-child {
  border-top: solid;
}
tr:nth-child(3n) td {
  border-bottom: solid;
}
input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row5">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row6">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row7">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row8">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row9">
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>Generate Array</button>
```

Comment: Just tested this out and it works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code. First, you're trying to find an element with the ID `table` (that's what `#table` targets). You don't have an element with the ID of `table`, so that instantly doesn't work. So you either need to give you table an ID, or change your selector to get the table. I'll suggest the latter, for now.

```
$('table')...
```

Secondly, instead of using `.children()`, try using the `$(selector, parent)` shorthand. `.children()` is awkward in the case of tables; it only selects direct children, and a TR is not a direct child (`tbody` is the direct child, even if you don't declare it in your markup). I avoid using `.children()`. If anything, use `.find()`.

```
$('tr', 'table').each(function() { ... });
```

Thirdly, you are using event.preventDefault(), but you haven't passed the event paramter to your callback. You need to pass the event, like so:

```
$('tr', 'table').each(function(event) { ... });
```

You will still only end up with a 1-dimensional array, not a 2-d array like you'd require, but this fixes the problems you had with your initial code.

Comment: @jmancherje Glad it helped mate. I haven't added the 2-dimensional array code as the other answer already covers it (I think).

Answer (score 0):

First point is, you haven't added id for table element. But you are taking reference of table id in function.That is how it was in fiddle code.

JS Code:

```
 var array = [];

    $('button').on('click', function(){
       // event.preventDefault();
        $('#table').find('tr').each(function(){
            var newarr=[];
            $(this).find('td input').each(function(){            
                newarr.push($(this).val());
                console.log('newarr:'+newarr);
            });
            array.push(newarr);
        });
        console.log(array);
    });
```

I have updated and code and the final result is printing in console.

Check it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [];

$('button').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    array = [];
    
    $('#table').find("tr").each(function(){
        var row = [];
        $(this).find('input').each(function(){
            row.push($(this).val());
        });
        array.push(row);
    });
    console.log(array);
});
```

```css
table {
  margin:1em auto;
}
td {
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border:1px solid;
  text-align:center;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left:solid;
}
td:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right:solid ;
}
tr:first-child {
  border-top:solid;
}
tr:nth-child(3n) td {
  border-bottom:solid ;
}
input {
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
}
button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr id="row4">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row5">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row6">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row7">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row8">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row9">
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>  
</table>

<button>Generate Array</button>
```